# AngularJS JSON object accessible in view, but not accessible in controller

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, model-view-controller

I have a simple service that gets some openWeather JSON. The service is then injected into the controller. In the controller, I cannot access the objects withing the JSON, however, when binding to the, I can access the object data without problem. I'm new to JS and Angular, what am I doing wrong?

**Service**

```
mcmdApp.service('areaWeatherService', ['$resource', function($resource){

    this.weatherAPI = $resource("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather", {get: {method: "JSON"}});
    this.weatherResult = this.weatherAPI.get({q: "London,uk"});

}]);
```

**Controller**

```
mcmdApp.controller('SingleElementController',['$scope', 'areaWeatherService',function($scope, areaWeatherService){

    $scope.weatherResult = areaWeatherService.weatherResult;
    console.log($scope.weatherResult); //<-- Shows Object in Console
    console.log($scope.weatherResult.wind); //<-- PROBLEM: Shows Undefined
    console.log($scope.weatherResult.wind.speed); //<-- PROBLEM: Shows cannot read property 'speed' of Undefined

}]);
```

**View**

```
<div class="single-element-widget text-center">
    <h2>{{weatherResult.wind.speed}} mph</h2><!-- NO PROBLEM, displays correctly -->
    <small>{{weatherResult.wind.deg}} degrees</small><!-- NO PROBLEM, displays correctly -->
</div>
```

I'm attempting to access the objects and properties from either the Controller or Service.

Results of `console.log($scope.weatherResult);`

```
e {$promise: d, $resolved: false}$promise: d$resolved: truebase: "cmc stations"clouds: Objectcod: 200coord: Objectdt: 1441164423id: 2643743main: Objectname: "London"sys: Objectweather: Array[1]wind: Object__proto__: e
```

Comment: Post the result of console.log($scope.weatherResult);

Comment: Edit: I have added the results of `console.log($scope.weatherResult);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're working with an `$http` promise. The log statement is firing before the data is returned from the server. Try this:

```
$scope.weatherResult = areaWeatherService.weatherResult.$promise.then(function(resp){
 console.log(resp);
 console.log(areaWeatherService.weatherResult.wind);
});
```

`.then()` will wait for your promise to be resolved, then execute the resulting code

Comment: This returned an error ".then is not a function". However, after adding `$promise` before `.then()` like this  `$scope.weatherResult = areaWeatherService.weatherResult.$promise.then(function(resp){
        console.log(resp);` It appears to be working.

Is this proper code?

Comment: Whoops! Yes, this is correct. I will update my answer accordingly for others. Congrats on figuring it out!

Comment: If I were to move the `$promise.then` to the service, so that the data is sent and received in the service, before passing to the controller, how  then would I access the `resp` object from withing the controller?

Scenario: suppose I wanted to inject this retrieved data into several controllers.